# MQTT on different network

Tags: java, sensors, mqtt

is probably a stupid question but I can not find answer on the internet. I need to have two separate networks geographically and I would like to communicate with the nodes of a network with nodes of the other network through a broker MQTT. This protocol allows you to do this or are constrained to be on the same network?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First line on Wikipedia:

> MQTT[1] (formerly Message Queue Telemetry Transport) is a publish-subscribe based "light weight" messaging protocol for use on top of the TCP/IP protocol. **It is designed for connections with remote locations** where a "small code footprint" is required and/or network bandwidth is limited.

Comment: That would be the second line I guess :P

Answer (score 1):

With MQTT you can have remote brokers and clients connecting. It has one-to-may message distribution over TCP/IP with a small transport overhead, one advantage of MQTT is that it supports TLS and ACL.

A good introduction post is here, http://jpmens.net/2013/02/25/lots-of-messages-mqtt-pub-sub-and-the-mosquitto-broker/